# Custom annotation for serialization

Tags: jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

How can I add custom annotations to the JMS Serializer?

The `JMS\Serializer\Metadata\Driver\AnnotationDriver` is not extendable for custom annotations.
Make it sense to overwrite it completely?

Thanks for ideas.